# Can't addEventListener('click', ...) to a div created programmatically

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I parse the result of `XMLHttprequest()` into a JSON object, then for each node of that object I create a div to store the informations.
Finally I add each div as `innerHTML` of a parent div.

Here the relevant part

```
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var html="";
        var linksDiv = document.getElementById('links');
        if (response.error != true){
          for (var i=0; i< response.links.length; i++){
            var l = response.links[i];
            var curId = l.id;
            var curLink = l.link;
            var curCreated = l.created_at;
            var curOrigin = l.origin;

            html =  "<div id=\"link"+curId+"\" >"+
                    "<label><b>Id </b></label><label>"+curId+"</label> </br>"+
                    "<label><b>Link </b></label><label>"+curLink+"</label> </br>"+
                    "<label><b>Created </b></label><label>"+curCreated+"</label> </br>"+
                    "<label><b>Origin </b></label><label>"+curOrigin+"</label> </br></br>"+
                    "</div>";
            linksDiv.innerHTML += html;

            var curDiv = document.getElementById('link'+curId);
            console.log("curDiv is"+'link'+curId);
            curDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){
             curDiv.style.background="gray";
             getLink(curId);
            });        
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

unfortunately

```
curDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){
             curDiv.style.background="gray";
             getLink(curId);
            });
```

doesn't work.

I already tried to make sure that the div exist (the `console.log("curDiv is"+'link'+curId);` works just fine)
and even used different ways like `curdDiv.onmouseover = function(){curDiv.style.background="gray";}`

If i put `curDiv.style.background="gray";` outside the `addEventListener()` every div's background gets correctly changed.

If i put `onmouseover="this.style.background='gray';"` as inline property of the div tag when i generate it, it works as well, but i don't want javascript in the html since I will transform this page in a Chrome Extension and javascript must be separated

Please don't get confused from the `mouseover` tries, I need onclick behavior, but was just testing different thing to see if they worked.

I looked for a long time on SO for an answer, as you can see from my tries, but couldn't find something that worked for me. Probably there is something that I don't get.

Ps.
Let me know if you need a sample JSON data to test the function.

Comment: What exactly did not work? I recreated your example and it worked. Just look at [my example](https://jsfiddle.net/5g7kuLu6/).

Comment: I see that it works! but in my case whenever i click on the div nothing happens!

Comment: Open the developer console in your browser and look if you get any error log messages. If yes, just post it here.

Comment: no errors, just the `console.log("curDiv is"+'link'+curId);` correctly working

Comment: Is there maybe an overlay above your div which captures the click event? Otherwise it should work in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use

```js
html = document.createElement('div');
html.id = 'link' + curId;

html.innerHTML = "<label><b>Id </b></label><label>" + curId 
+ "</label> </br><label><b>Link </b></label><label>" + curLink
+ "</label> </br><label><b>Created </b></label><label>" + curCreated
+ "</label> </br><label><b>Origin </b></label><label>" + curOrigin
+ "</label> </br></br>";

html.addEventListener('click', function(){
     this.style.background="gray";
     getLink(this.id);
}); 

linksDiv.appendChild(html);
```

instead of

```js
html =  "<div id=\"link"+curId+"\" >"+
                    "<label><b>Id </b></label><label>"+curId+"</label> </br>"+
                    "<label><b>Link </b></label><label>"+curLink+"</label> </br>"+
                    "<label><b>Created </b></label><label>"+curCreated+"</label> </br>"+
                    "<label><b>Origin </b></label><label>"+curOrigin+"</label> </br></br>"+
                    "</div>";
linksDiv.innerHTML += html;
var curDiv = document.getElementById('link'+curId);
console.log("curDiv is"+'link'+curId);
curDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){
    curDiv.style.background="gray";
    getLink(curId);
});
```

Comment: close! now the EventListener works on every div, but since it's inside a for loop, every onclick passes to `getLink` the same (and last) id found. Also whatever div i click, only the last one changes background. how can i do?

Comment: Try

`html.addEventListener('click', function(){
             this.style.background="gray";
             getLink(this.id);
            });  `

instead of 
`var curDiv = document.getElementById('link'+curId);
            console.log("curDiv is"+'link'+curId);
            curDiv.addEventListener('click', function(){
             curDiv.style.background="gray";
             getLink(curId);
            });`

Answer (score 0):

Check this working code. make delay so that event will attached to element.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function populateLink() {
                var html = "";
                var linksDiv = document.getElementById('links');
                for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    var l = 'l-' + i;
                    var curId = i;
                    var curLink = 'l.link-' + i;
                    var curCreated = 'l.created_at_' + 1;
                    var curOrigin = 'l.origin_' + i;

                    html = "<div id=\"link" + curId + "\" >" +
                            "<label><b>Id </b></label><label>" + curId + "</label> </br>" +
                            "<label><b>Link </b></label><label>" + curLink + "</label> </br>" +
                            "<label><b>Created </b></label><label>" + curCreated + "</label> </br>" +
                            "<label><b>Origin </b></label><label>" + curOrigin + "</label> </br></br>" +
                            "</div>";
                    linksDiv.innerHTML += html;

                    //var curDiv = document.getElementById('link' + curId)
                    //curDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    //    this.style.background = "gray";
                    //    getLink(this.id);
                    //});

                   attachEvent(curId);
                }
            }

            function attachEvent(curId) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    var curDiv = document.getElementById('link' + curId)
                    curDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
                        this.style.background = "gray";
                        //getLink(this.id);
                    });
                }, 100);
            }
            window.onload = populateLink;
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="links"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```